# jQuery select each element from one div and paste into each another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need jQuery function for selecting each `"a"` html code from one div and paste it into each another li.

Copy from this `div` each `"a"`

```
    <div class="copy-from-this-div">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
    </div>
```

Paste into this each `li`:

```
<ul class="paste-into-this-div">
   <li class="images" ></li>
   <li class="images" ></li>
   <li class="images" ></li>

</ul>
```

And in a conclusion I need to remove first `div`.

This is what I tried to make, but it doesnt work.

```
$('.paste-into-this-div').each(function(s, slider){
var $slider = $(slider);

$('.copy-from-this-div').each(function(i, select){
    var $select = $(select);
    $select.find('a').each(function(j, option){
        var $option = $(option);

$slider.append($option);    

    });
    $select.remove();
});  
});
```

Comment: did you make an attempt?

Comment: Yes of course. I will add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing your are trying to appending  `a` element inside `ul` element it wouldn't be see in the page.

Optimized way
https://jsfiddle.net/zyz3qymn/2/

```
$('.copy-from-this-div a').each(function(i, select){
  $('.paste-into-this-div').find('li')[i].append(select);    
});
```

We can do like this also
https://jsfiddle.net/zyz3qymn/1/

```
$('.copy-from-this-div').each(function(i, select){
    var $select = $(select);
    $select.find('a').each(function(j, option){
        $('.paste-into-this-div').find('li')[j].append(option);    
                $select.remove();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a pure JavaScript solution, a bit clearer.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.copy-from-this-div');
var a = div.querySelectorAll('a');
var li = document.querySelectorAll('.paste-into-this-div li');

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].appendChild(a[i]);
}

div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

```html
<div class="copy-from-this-div">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="#">
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="#">
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="#">
  </a>
</div>

<ul class="paste-into-this-div">
  <li class="images"></li>
  <li class="images"></li>
  <li class="images"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are assuming that all elements inside an anchor are images and maybe that's not always the case - good approach though.

Answer (score 0):

### Easy peasy

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.copy-from-this-div a').each(function(i, a) {
    // Get all images and the corresponding 'li' 
    var images = $(a).find('img'),
        li = $('.paste-into-this-div li').eq(i);

    // Add the images
    $(li).append(images);

    // Remove the link
    $(this).remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="copy-from-this-div">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="#">
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="#">
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="#">
  </a>
</div>
<ul class="paste-into-this-div">
  <li class="images"></li>
  <li class="images"></li>
  <li class="images"></li>
</ul>
```